# What is the appropriate format for the returned data from EntityManager.saveChanges (when not using .Net)?

Tags: breeze

I'm developing the server-side of an app that uses BreezeJS on the front end to manage the model interactions.  The server-side platform is ColdFusion, which doesn't have built-in EF or OData support so I am writing the server interface to produce/consume the metadata as used by the default webapi adapter.

Currently I am prototyping this using the sample AngularJS ToDo app from the BreezeJS download.  So far I am able to fetch the metadata, query the model and even save changes to the server (using the sample app's js code), however when the EntityManager.saveChanges() method is fired I get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Errors' of null`
in the breeze.debug.js file during the "success" method of the ajax post in the `ctor.prototype.saveChanges` method.  Apparently the server is required to return some data after save.  So what is the data that needs to come back from the server?  If I return the saved entities in the same format as was posted I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'map' of undefined`

The error occurs in the breeze.debug.js file when calling the method: `ctor.prototype._prepareSaveResult`.

I'm surely missing some document that explains this, so if you could point me in the right direction that would be great too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The save result is an object with three properties.

- **Entities**: An array of entities that were sent to the server, with their values updated by the server.  For example, temporary ID values get replaced by server-generated IDs.
- **KeyMappings**: An array of objects that tell Breeze which temporary IDs were replaced with which server-generated IDs.  Each object has an `EntityTypeName`, `TempValue`, and `RealValue`.
- **Errors**: An array of `EntityError` objects, indicating validation errors that were found on the server.  This will be null if there were no errors.  Each object has an `ErrorName`, `EntityTypeName`, `KeyValues` array, `PropertyName`, and `ErrorMessage`.

All of the property names in the save result are case sensitive.

Here's an example of what a save result might look like when saving a single Order object.  Notice that the Order contains a `$type` property so Breeze can match it up with its client-side metadata.  Also notice that the KeyMappings shows that the Order's temporary key -1 was replaced with its server-generated value 262013.

```
{
"Entities":[
    {"$type":"northwind.model.Order","customerID":"7852","orderID":262013,"rowVersion":0}],
"Errors":null,
"KeyMappings":[
    {"EntityTypeName":"northwind.model.Order","RealValue":262013,"TempValue":-1}]
}
```

Kudos to you for building your own server backend for Breeze.

Comment: Thanks for the excelent answer @Steve!  I'm that much closer now :). Unfortunately the native ColdFusion JSON serializer doesn't handle null values (treats them as strings) and when I return the struct per your example with `"Errors":"null"` it tries to run the error handler and fails saying the `object has no method 'map'`. Passing an empty array doesn't error, but causes the fail callback to run. I can write my own serializer, but if that can be avoided I'd rather go that route. Any suggestions on that front?

Comment: You can leave the `Errors` property out entirely - for a successful save, only the Entities and KeyMappings are needed.  If necessary, create two separate types of objects, one that has an Errors property and one that does not.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks for your help Steve.  By removing the `Errors` array when there are no errors I am fully operational (as far as the Todo sample)!